# How did Maurice know the dying soldier can't speak?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes, planet-of-the-apes-2011, war-for-the-planet-of-the-apes

In *War for the Planet of the Apes (2017)*, The apes and Nova pass through the snowy mountains. They find the bodies of three soldiers shot in the snow. One of them is still alive but is slowly dying. Caesar asks Maurice why he was shot, and Maurice replied "Soldier can't speak, like Nova".

[image: Maurice and Nova looking at the dying body]

How did Maurice know the dying soldier can't speak?

Comment: How are you so sure that he **knew**, rather than just making an educated guess based on the existence of non-speaking humans and this soldier not speaking?

Comment: @Flater I don't remember, but had they found multiple mute humans before Nova? Otherwise, to them, Nova would be simply a mute human, of which there are some in the real world :) Given that you know non-speaking people exist, how quick would you be in considering a dying person is mute?

Comment: @AndresF.: From what I remember from the movie, the dying soldier was trying to communicate (obvious from his facial language) but unable to make sound, while his condition was not obviously blocking his ability to speak. The only logical conclusion would be that he's unable to speak, and not because of his injuries. That seems like a fair definition of mute. And again, this doesn't need to be an objectively correct assumption, Maurice simply needs to _think_ that his assumption is reasonably correct.

Comment: @Flater Yes, I understand about Maurice and assumptions. What I'm saying is that it doesn't make sense for Maurice to even consider this; he is being "too clever" because the mute virus is a plot device. If I found a dying soldier with a chest wound who's unable to speak, I'd think "of course, the punctured lung prevents him from speaking" instead of "he must be mute!". The soldier was half-dead anyway.